# Javascript animation with TimeLine won't play within html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add [this codepen animation](https://codepen.io/uamor/pen/XYxRrK) to a webpage. To do this I have,

1. placed the html code into the correct location in the index.html, and added `<script src="js/phoenix.js"></script>` as the last line in the `body` block.
2. created a file js/phoenix.js for the javascript code.
3. added `.phoenix{height: 50vmin; left: calc(100% - 25vmin); top: calc(100% - 33vmin); position: absolute; width: auto;}` to the end of the css.stlye file.

This results in placing the graphic on my webpage as desired, but the animation does not run. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you add external js showing in pen settings tab. jquery.min.js, GSDevTools.min.js, TweenMax.min.js.

Comment: And also i don't think you can use Greensock plugin for free, but it will work for a little.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the `GSDevTools.create({});` line is not used; it's for the codepen demo only.

Comment: Ahh I see, the external js scripts you mention @codesayan are required in the index.html :)

Comment: These scripts are required but there is another requirement for one of them. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GSDevTools` used for the timeline is a "Club GreenSock" plugin that you can freely try on codepen but not on your website without a subscription (see https://codepen.io/GreenSock/full/djXzyR).